# Requires capabilities : [CAPABILITY_IAM] Cloudformation AWS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am getting `Requires capabilities : [CAPABILITY_IAM]` error when creating a stack on cloudformation.
[image]

Now I know we need to execute the command to create the stack with following parameter `--capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM` when using AWS CLI.

Question is how do I change the setting or solve this issue when using cloudformation from aws console so that I am able to create the stack by uploading the script using web console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the review pages you have option to allow that:

[image]

Comment: @SaadAhmed No problem.Glad it worked out:-)